# Can I let shape with liquify effect like photoshop by p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to create an irregular lines with liquify effect like photoshop. Also, want to implement it by p5.js.
Is it possible use some mathematical formula to create line like the referring image.
Or how can I do this effect? Any idea can guide me. thanks a lot!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is for sure an algorythm to liquify something. But there is way too much information missing on what you are trying to do, or what the photoshop-effect looks like.

I'd suggest you start small. Draw a vertical line in P5 center of your screen. (Loop to draw each dot individually). Now for every y of your line use a random value provided by "Open Simplex". Offset the dot x-position by the random value. Tip: Use a fixed seed.

When using the OpenSimplex. You will have to use any of those: noise2D, noise3D, noise4D

You can use any you want. The important thing is you modify only one value by your y and one by time (frameCount for example). The value you get back will be a little different from the previous one every time. Like this you will get a random value for every iteration, but a random value which is not too different from the previous value of y. Thats how the liquidity illusion is provided.

Read up on OpenSimplex.

This is the 2D(+1D [Time]) Version of it: https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/MPqnctIGg

Comment: HI SirPilan, thanks for your suggestion. As you guess, I have do some testing like this -> https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1729926.  And Actually I want to do the effect like this image(https://i.imgur.com/kjAPWYL.png). I have read some OpenSimplex information as you said. but I still not sure how can I use this. Can you give me more guide? Really thank you very much~

Comment: "Can you give me more guide?" - sorry no. But I kinda did explain what you need to begin with. Try to analyze and understand the code for the 2D/3D Version (found in sketch.js). If you have first results and specific questions I'm happy to help.